# Getting news AND comments at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

news

`news_id | header | text`

news_comments

`comment_id | comment | date | fk_news_id`

Currently I just pull out the news. However, I want to pull the comments as well, but I am not quite sure if I can make a single query, or if I should pull the news first, and THEN the comments.

Which method (if both possible) would be the better one?

Comment: why you are not using inner join?

Comment: Doing it that way produces a news item for each comment.If there is 3 comments on a news item, that item will be pulled from the database 3 times in the result

Comment: would a broader table containing a union of a news-query and a comments-query be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly if that is what you have in mind...

```
SELECT 'N' AS type, news_id, header, text, NULL AS date
FROM news
UNION
SELECT 'C' AS type, fk_news_id AS news_id, NULL AS header, comment AS text, date
FROM comments
ORDER BY news_id, type desc
```

this would provide you a single result set, but you have to consider the different column names when retrieving the comments data from the result

Comment: This seems reasonably practical, for a small number of similar columns. You might consider `UNION ALL` since you know that all columns are already distinct

Answer (score 2):

use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    news a
        INNER JOIN news_comments b
            ON a.news_ID = b.fk_news_id
ORDER   BY a.news_ID, b.comment_ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

The statement above will only return `news` that has at least one comment, if you want to return all news even without comments, use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    news a
        LEFT JOIN news_comments b
            ON a.news_ID = b.fk_news_id
ORDER   BY a.news_ID, b.comment_ID
```

Comment: Doing it this way produces a news item for each comment.If there is 3 comments on a news item, that item will be pulled from the database 3 times in the result

Comment: Unfortunately yes, how do you want your comments to be shown? or why not format it on the application level?

Comment: I could do that, but is that really more efficient than pulling the comments out on its own, after news have been pulled?

Comment: can you give sample output on what you are talking? i can't think of another way using query.

Comment: The alternative I can think of, is making a query for the news and a query for the comments :-)